# Disable text selection in WebView on WP8.1

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a WebView which loads a HTML file with a PrivacyPolicy, but I don't want users to be able to select and copy text. How can this be achieved?

Here's my code:

```
<WebView x:Name="LicenseWebview"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Source="ms-appx-web:///Assets/License/en.html"
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using JavaScript or CSS. Here's the answer from [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96c4dffd-be76-482e-aaf9-f0feba95532c/how-can-i-make-webview-nonselectable?forum=winappswithcsharp) which addresses this issue. Hope this helps.

```
<html onselectstart="return false;" style="-ms-user-select: none;">
...
</html>
```